# Centering an absolutely positioned div over a bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to center a div on top of a bootstrap grid and have it remain centered with the responsive layout (regardless of screen size). Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/rCus6zrKx9) of what I'm trying to do. How can I center the .ontop div on the grid?

Oops should have poked around more. I found this works pretty well:

```
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
left: 50%;
top: 25%;
margin-left: -40%;
margin-right: -40%;
```

Comment: This won't work proper when you resize your browser because it's just optimized for your current view. I recommend you to use `transform: translate()` which guarantees that your element is centered.

Comment: you also need a fixed width and height not percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the following:

```
.container .ontop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The `top/left` properties move the element by 50% of the width of the parrent element horizontally/vertically. The `transform: translate()` moves the element back by half of its width/height.